# django tutorial/app - error when running python manage.py sql polls

Tags: django

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm getting this error and not sure how to fix.

```
C:\dj_stuff\mysite> python manage.py sql polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\dj_stuff\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 127
    )   'polls',
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: The traceback is pointing you to a syntax error in "C:\dj_stuff\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 127. Take a look there and fix it...

Comment: Sorry, guys.  I read it again and fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please paste settings.py.
lines from 100 to 130

but... look at this line:

```
 )   'pools',
```

you've added appname after tuple.
you should add 'pools' one line upper, before ')'